# How to skip generation of testBuilder with AutoValue in generic class

Tags: java, generics, code-generation, auto-value

### Autovalue version: 1.3

Given the following class:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class SimpleClass<T> {
    public static <E> SimpleClass<E> create(Set<? extends E> someField) {
        return SimpleClass.<E>builder().someField(someField).build();
    }

    public static <E> Builder<E> builder() {
        return new AutoValue_SimpleClass.Builder<E>();
    }

    public abstract ImmutableSet<T> someField();

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder<T> {
        public abstract Builder<T> someField(Set<? extends T> someField);
        public abstract SimpleClass<T> build();
    }
}
```

When auto builder generates the sources for the above class, it generates something like:

```
final class AutoValue_SimpleClass<T> extends $AutoValue_SimpleClass<T> {
  AutoValue_SimpleClass(ImmutableSet<T> someField) {
    super(someField);
  }

  static SimpleClass.Builder<E> testBuilder() {
      return builder();
  }
}
```

Notice how the generic method `testBuilder` is incorrectly generated because it needs `<E>` after `static`.

This is what should have been generated:

```
static <E> SimpleClass.Builder<E> testBuilder() {
    return builder();
}
```

Is there a way to not have this `testBuilder` method generated or a way to ensure that `AutoValue` generates the right sources?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** *Just updated to 1.4 and the same thing is still happening*

**Issue on GH: https://github.com/google/auto/issues/511**

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to compile.  Shouldn't it be `public abstract ImmutableSet<T> someField();` with `T` instead of `E`?  `E` is not in scope at that point.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, that was a typo. Fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was surprisingly not too involved:

*Just rename the static `builder` method*

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class SimpleClass<T> {
    public static <E> SimpleClass<E> create(Set<? extends E> someField) {
        return SimpleClass.<E>getBuilder().someField(someField).build();
    }

    public static <E> Builder<E> getBuilder() {
        return new AutoValue_SimpleClass.Builder<E>();
    }

    public abstract ImmutableSet<T> someField();

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder<T> {
        public abstract Builder<T> someField(Set<? extends T> someField);
        public abstract SimpleClass<T> build();
    }
}
```

This means `testBuilder` method is no longer generated.

Comment: This is an issue with an AutoValue extension rather than with AutoValue itself.

Comment: @emcmanus, Thanks for the heads up. I will disable the plugin for the time being